# Java inheritance error handling scenario

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, spring

I looked multiple places for some advice on how to solve this before asking this question, but I couldn't find something similar to this.

So I have the following scenario in Java Spring Integration

Let's say I have some super class type

```
class Foo {
    private String error;
    public Foo(error) {
       this.error = error;
    }
    public boolean isError(){
       return !(error.equals("SUCCESS"));
    }
 }
```

and then a few subclasses

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    private String name;

    public Bar(String name) {
        this.name = name
        super("SUCCESS");
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    // more methods
 }
```

And there are more classes that are subclasses of `Foo` each with different methods. Now I have a Spring integration Gateway Facade that returns the supertype Foo, with a route that contacts different endpoints and returns a different subclass of Foo based on the request, or in some cases an error which is actually an instantiation of Foo containing the error string. The error comes from the Facades error handler.

```
public interface Facade {
   Foo facadeMethod(Map<String, String> requestMap);
}

public class ErrorHandler {
   // arguments not important hence "..."
   public Foo handle(...) {
        return new Foo("ERROR");
   }
}
```

The way I am currently handling this is:

```
Foo response = facade.facadeMethod(requestMap);
if (response.isError()) {
  // do something
}
Bar bar = (Bar)response;
String name = bar.name();
// something with bar methods
```

It is guaranteed that if `isError` is false, the type I downcast to is actually of the subclass type. The route is selected based on a key/value pair in the `requestMap`.

I could throw an exception instead of having an error code, but I still have the same issue of needing to downcast since the facade needs to return a more general type (super class). I don't see how to use generics to solve this, since the Facade method is not in the inheritance hierarchy of Foo/Bar and the other sub classes. I also thought about using a factory but I didn't see how to use that either.

This all feels messy, and I would like to avoid downcasting. Is there any way that is cleaner and better Java practice, or am I stuck with downcasting? Maybe I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: This sounds like what you really want is an [Either type](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/Either.html) Because Java doesn't have one built in, I'm leaving this as a comment. Writing your own wouldn't be that difficult though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following mechanism: you have no `if`s, no generics, no casts, no dangerous variables and a typesafe answer.

```
interface Response {
  void handle(Feedback feedback);
}

interface Feedback {
  default void onSuccess(Success success) {}
  default void onError(Error error) {}
}

class Success implements Response {
  String name;
  Success(String name) { this.name = name; }
  String name() { return name; }
  public void handle(Feedback feedback) {
    feedback.onSuccess(this);
  }
}

class Error implements Response {
  public void handle(Feedback feedback) {
    feedback.onError(this);
  }
}
```

Then, just use it like this:

```
Feedback feedback = new Feedback() {
  public void onSuccess(Success success) {
    String name = success.name();
    // Do something with Success methods
  }
  public void onError(Error error) {
    // Do something with Error methods
  }
};
Response response = facade.facadeMethod(requestMap);
response.handle(feedback);
```

Notes:

- I renamed `Foo` to `Response` and `Bar` to `Success` for the clarity of the answer.
- I got rid of your error mechanism implementation because it was better handled this way. The "guarantee" you requested now comes from the distinction in two different feedback methods: `onSuccess` and `onError`.
- It can be extended by creating new `Response` subtypes and new `on...` methods. You can of course call the same `on...` method for two different responses: it's the reponse's responsibility to call the feedback's appropriate method.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Also, what if `onSuccess` needs to return something? Like it constructs a new object, call it `ClientData`, out of the data it gets from the `Success` object. How can this response be propagated up to return of `handle` in a clean way? Basically, if the last block of code you wrote is in some method that wraps around the spring-integration functionality, and in the end returns the `ClientData` to the client.

Comment: and for another `on...` it returns something else as that `on...` was called from a different wrapper method that results in a different integration response.

Comment: @dylan7 For the `ClientData`, you can always keep working in the `onSuccess` method. If you use a HTTP client, for instance, you get a `HTTPResponse` somewhere or something similar. Then you can most certainly, in your `onSuccess` call `httpResponse.write(clientData)`. Another possibility if you really want to `return` is to return `Optional<ClientData>` instead of `void`. If you use some Json API, there is usually a possibility to get a response holder as parameter, mostly because asynchronicity is a thing now, and that's how you publish asynchronous responses.

Comment: So going the `return` route,  if `Optional<ClientData>` needed to be propagated up to the `return` of `handle` would we the need `handle` to have a generic `return` type? Since not every class that implements `Response` will `return` `Optional<ClientData>` in its `handle`. Since you mentioned asynchronicity, this is starting to feel like a `Future`-like pattern, which uses a generic.